# How to select unique entries

Tags: sql

I have a table of network devices interfaces (link_id points to id):

```
id      |device     |interface      |link_id
1       |switch1    |Gi1/1          |2
2       |switch2    |Gi1/1          |1
...
```

My goal is to have following connectivity matrix:

```
device_a    |interface_a    |device_b   |interface_b
switch1     |Gi1/1          |switch2    |Gi1/1
```

Which I thought I can get with:

```
SELECT a.device, a.interface, b.device, b.interface
FROM `links` a
INNER JOIN `links` b ON a.id = b.link_id
```

But as a result I get a "reverse" record as well:

```
device_a    |interface_a    |device_b   |interface_b
switch1     |Gi1/1          |switch2    |Gi1/1
switch2     |Gi1/1          |switch1    |Gi1/1
```

How can I select only unique entries? Is there any smarter way to achieve this task? (different table structure may be)

Comment: You could generate a composite id from the join so that you can filter later on, like `1-2` for your example and make sure the id is sorted so that you don't get `2-1`.

Comment: or, for a quick solution, add `WHERE a.id < b.link_id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you move your `link_id` column to a new table to relate `id` and `link_id` (renamed `id_a` and `id_b` below), the query for this becomes simple with 2 JOINs. This table structure also normalizes your data, because now the relationship between 2 interfaces is stored in a separate many-to-many table, not as additional IDs in the `interface` table.

```
CREATE TABLE interfaces (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `device` VARCHAR(7),
  `interface` VARCHAR(5)
);

INSERT INTO interfaces
  (`id`, `device`, `interface`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'switch1', 'Gi1/1'),
  ('2', 'switch2', 'Gi1/1');
  
CREATE TABLE links (
  `id_a` INTEGER,
  `id_b` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO links
    (`id_a`, `id_b`)
VALUES
    ('1', '2');
```

---

```
SELECT
    i.device as device_a,
    i.interface interface_a,
    i2.device as device_b,
    i2.interface as inteface_b
FROM
    links l
    JOIN interfaces i ON i.id = l.id_a
    JOIN interfaces i2 ON i2.id = l.id_b;
```

| device_a | interface_a | device_b | inteface_b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| switch1 | Gi1/1 | switch2 | Gi1/1 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eaVWsBDNyLz6uvwofSKZYk/0)

Answer (score 2):

add a condition like this:

```
SELECT a.device, a.interface, b.device, b.interface
FROM `links` a
INNER JOIN `links` b 
   ON a.id = b.link_id
   AND a.id < a.link_id
```