# How to make all WHERE conditions optional MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

I have already reviewed similar questions like the following:

- [PHP and MySQL optional WHERE conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15212081/php-and-mysql-optional-where-conditions)

Avoid using `PHP`, for this and, try it with direct conditions in `MYSQL`, having the following:

```
$datetime_index = $_POST["dateIndex"];
$datetime_end = $_POST["dateEnd"];
$id_customer = $_POST["customer"];
$id_team = $_POST["team"];
$stmt = $con->prepare(
            "SELECT id_logtrama, register_datatime, id_customer,
                    id_team,statusGlobal
                FROM logtrama
                WHERE register_datatime BETWEEN (@datetime_index IS NULL OR '$datetime_index') 
                AND (@datetime_end IS NULL OR '$datetime_end') 
                AND (@id_customer IS NULL OR id_customer=?) 
                AND (@id_team IS NULL OR id_team=?)
                LIMIT 10");
$stmt->bind_param("ii", $id_customer, $id_team);
```

Test like this:

```
WHERE register_datatime BETWEEN ('$datetime_index') AND ('$datetime_end') 
AND (@id_customer IS NULL OR id_customer=?) 
AND (@id_team IS NULL OR id_team=?)
```

And, it worked correctly, when showing data only by start of date and, end of date, data was displayed correctly.

However, what I want is that all `WHERE` conditions are optional, for the first attempt I have no problems, however applying the same condition to `register_datatime BETWEEN` does not show me results:

```
WHERE register_datatime BETWEEN (@datetime_index IS NULL OR '$datetime_index') 
AND (@datetime_end IS NULL OR '$datetime_end') 
AND (@id_customer IS NULL OR id_customer=?) 
AND (@id_team IS NULL OR id_team=?)
```

In conclusion, if all the conditions are null, all the records in the database are printed.

Comment: I think you answered your own question with the last sentence - essentially, "return all results when all conditions are null, otherwise apply the previously defined logic: `WHERE (@datetime_index IS NULL AND @datetime_end IS NULL AND @id_customer IS NULL AND @id_team IS NULL) OR (register_datatime BETWEEN ? AND ? AND id_customer = ? AND id_team = ?)` (Side note: you should parameterize `$datetime_index` and `$datetime_end` the same way you pass customer/team ID to avoid SQL injection.)

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones As it is done in the same way, could you explain that to me, I understand that it is added when the conditions are like this `id_customer =?`

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones It should be noted friend that `datetime_index ` and `datetime_end` are not columns of the data table, they are data variables that have date, I want to make sure that mentioning this, what you indicate is correct?

Comment: [Without sample data it's hard to say for certain.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/1499877) So if you could add that to your question, future suggestions will be less of a guess. But the way it works is that if all 4 conditions are NULL, then the `WHERE` clause is essentially `WHERE true OR (something else)`. `true OR (something)` always evaluates to `true`, so all results should be returned. If even one of the 4 columns isn't null though, then your condition becomes `WHERE false OR (something else)` so the `(something else)` logic gets applied to your columns instead.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones I have updated my question, where is the complete code of the query.

Comment: As described at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, "If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so". Please add sample data so we can see an example of the data you are expecting. (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/67200183/1499877 is a good question that shows their tables with example data, as well as what their expected result is. That's what I mean when I say "sample data".)

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones The example shown does not work, when I try to choose a single filter from the client, it prints all the records.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones I do not know how to use it, I have the following filters: https://jsfiddle.net/0zan5cjy/1/, to which if you do not enter anything, it will show all the records, if you only enter the start date, it will show all the data that matches the date, if you enter the start date and date In the same way, in the same way, show records of those given parameters, if you are going to filter only by customer, only records of the customer are shown, if you are going to filter by equipment then record by equipment or in date + customer combinations and so on.

Comment: Where do you set variables like `@datetime_end`?

Comment: Why are you mixing variable interpolation and `bind_param`? Use `bind_param` for everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your parameter variables to `null` if the field is unset or blank. Then you can check `? IS NULL` in the query.

```
$datetime_index = empty($_POST["dateIndex"]) ? null : $_POST["dateIndex"];
$datetime_end = empty($_POST["dateEnd"]) ? null : $_POST["dateEnd"];
$id_customer = empty($_POST["customer"]) ? null : $_POST["customer"];
$id_team = empty($_POST["team"]) ? null : $_POST["team"];
$stmt = $con->prepare(
            "SELECT id_logtrama, register_datatime, id_customer,
                    id_team,statusGlobal
                FROM logtrama
                WHERE ((? IS NULL OR ? IS NULL) OR register_datatime BETWEEN ? AND ?) 
                AND (? IS NULL OR id_customer=?) 
                AND (? IS NULL OR id_team=?)
                LIMIT 10");
$stmt->bind_param("ssssiiii", $datetime_index, $datetime_end, $datetime_index, $datetime_end, $id_customer, $id_customer, $id_team, $id_team);
```

Comment: it works for the other filters, client and, team, but when I try to filter start date and end date it does not show me results

Comment: Are the start and end dates formatted properly for MySQL? They need to be `YYYY-MM-DD` format. If they're some other format, use `STR_TO_DATE()` to parse them.

Comment: Or convert the format in PHP.

Comment: make this change: `$stmt->bind_param("ssssiiii", $datetime_index, $datetime_end, $datetime_index, $datetime_end, $id_customer, $id_customer, $id_team, $id_team);`, I think I was sending the same condition to the start date and the end date, I am correct or not, this is how it worked but I don't know if it is the correct thing, if the dates are correct.

Comment: date is correct but it would not be bad to add that parameter in case they try to add an incorrect format, as I add that condition `STR_TO_DATE()`

Comment: You're right, I put them in the wrong order.

Comment: This condition `STR_TO_DATE ()` how should I add it

Comment: If dates are in the format `MM/DD/YYYY`: `register_datatime BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(?, '%m/%d/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE(?, '%m/%d/%Y')`